# JS - FullCalendar : Listen when the month changes

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm having a little issue with FullCalendar v5, I configured it with the `dayGridMonth` View and I would like **to listen when the user changes the current month** ...

For example, if he is seeing February and click on `next` he'll see march, so I was expected for a handler like `onChange` or `onMonthChange` but I didn't find anything in the documentation to do something like this ...

I figured how to get around the problem by making my own prev / next buttons and triggering my custom handler on the click ... But I would like to know if there is a vanilla way to do it?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Refer https://fullcalendar.io/docs/datesSet

Comment: Wow ... thanks you ! Exactly what I was looking for ! They really should improve their documentation (or at least put a searchbox)

Comment: Why do you want to know when the month changes? If you're trying to make it load more events then see the section on event sources instead - https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-source

Comment: @ADyson ths main reason is to load some datas from the current month but not print them in the calendar ... I need to add a class to the .fc-daygrid-day-frame if the event has been registered ...

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure if I understand... you want to change some CSS of the calendar if there is an event on a particular date, but you don't want to show the event itself on the calendar...is that correct?

Comment: @ADyson yep :) I'll try to explain better ... My feature is for the client to daily send some datas I keep in my Database. So to select the date I use Full Calendar and the goal is to color in green the days he already sent and in red the past days he didn't ... I don't need to add some events and I don't want to load ALL the datas at the beginning, I just want to load the data of the current month ...

Comment: `the goal is to color in green the days he already sent `...for that you could use fullcalendar's Background Events feature (with the data supplied via an event feed), rather than mucking about with the CSS manually or needing to handle datesSet. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/background-events and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed . It will fulfil all your requirements in a nicer way.

Comment: I'll see later if this solution is more suitable ... But I think this will be hardest because I need to add some headers on the event sources which seems impossible in the doc ? And I need to listen the month change because I also have some extra logic to implement outside of my calendar but linked with the view displayed :)

Comment: What do you mean by "headers"? You mean HTTP headers? If you need to make a custom HTTP request then you can implement the same concept via https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function instead - it lets you define the AJAX code yourself. You could also implement the other extra logic there too, if necessary.

Comment: I think this is more usable for my case ... I'll check it later :) Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentionned by @Devsi Odedra, the answer was `datesSet`

The doc : https://fullcalendar.io/docs/datesSet

This is my actual code if it can help someone :

```js
new Calendar(document.getElementById("calendar"), {
    plugins: [ dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin ],
    datesSet: event => {
        // As the calendar starts from prev month and end in next month I take the day between the range
        var midDate = new Date((event.start.getTime() + event.end.getTime()) / 2).getMonth()
        var month = `0${ midDate.getMonth() + 1 }`.splice(0, -1)
        doSomethingOnThisMonth(month, midDate.getFullYear())
    }
});

function doSomethingOnThisMonth(month, year) {
    fetch(`myApi.com/something?month=${ month }&year=${ year }`)
        .then((result) => {
            // Do something
        })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted the same Functionality of Triggering a Function if the Month Changes in UI of fullCalendar, I didn't get it on Google but got references to handle the Situation here is how my Function gets triggered, Using "useEffect" Hook in React! & and "Month" as its "Dependency!"

```js
//Call this function Inside the ,

/*   datesSet={function(dateInfo) {  
          monthRange(dateInfo)
      }} */ 


const monthRange = (dateInfo)=>{

  
  const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];


          let startDate =  dateInfo.view.activeStart.toLocaleDateString()
          let endDate =  dateInfo.view.activeEnd.toLocaleDateString()
          let yy =  dateInfo.view.activeStart.getFullYear()




          let dd = new Date(dateInfo.view.activeStart.getDate());
          
          let monthNum = dateInfo.view.activeStart.getMonth()
          let mm =0;

          if( dd >24){
      
           mm =  monthNames[ monthNum +1];
           if(monthNum ===11){
            mm = monthNames[0]
          }
          }

          else{
            mm =  monthNames[monthNum];
          }       
          setDateStart(startDate)
          setDateEnd(endDate)
          setCurrMonth(mm)

          console.log("Month Number...", monthNum, mm)     
            
}
          
          
          useEffect(() => {
            alert(`
            "Start"=>   ${dateStart} , 
            "End"=>  ${dateEnd}
            "Month Changed"=> ${currMonth}` )

   //Write here Fetch Funtion, Triggers on Month Change in FullCalendar
   
   
   
          }, [currMonth])
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```